# How to use type check Loopback / Fireloop PersistedModel

Tags: loopback, fireloop

I'm using Fireloop with Loopback 3 and wanting to know how best to create typesafe hooks and remote methods using type checked `PersistedModel` and `Validatable` methods.  I'd like to change the type of the constructor from ...

`constructor(public model: any) { }`

to ...

`constructor(public model: SomeType) { }`

I'd like to make PersistedModel calls like

```
this.model.count().then((n) => ...);
```

OR Validatable calls like:

```
model.validatesLengthOf('code', { 
    min: 6, max: 12, message: { min: 'too short',  max: 'too long'} 
});
```

The Fireloop examples like the one below only use `any` as type of `this.model`.
The [firestarter model samples](https://github.com/mean-expert-official/fire-starter/tree/development/api/common/models) and Fireloop documentation were also of no use here.

I know that there is a type called `ModelConstructor` declared in the fireloop source tree under [core/index.d.ts](https://github.com/mean-expert-official/fireloop.io/blob/master/core/index.d.ts). This interface looks correct because it implements all the `PersistedModel` and `Validatable` methods but where is it published in npmjs? Is it already part of the Fireloop server SDK or do I need to `npm install` it? No idea.

```
import { Model } from '@mean-expert/model';

/**
 * @module Account
 * @description
 * Write a useful Account Model description.
 * Register hooks and remote methods within the
 * Model Decorator
 **/
@Model({
  hooks: {
    beforeSave: { name: 'before save', type: 'operation' }
  },
  remotes: {
    myRemote: {
      returns: { arg: 'result', type: 'array' },
      http: { path: '/my-remote', verb: 'get' }
    }
  }
})

class Account {
  // LoopBack model instance is injected in constructor
  constructor(public model: any) { }

  // Example Operation Hook
  beforeSave(ctx: any, next: Function): void {
    console.log('Account: Before Save', ctx.instance);    
    next();
  }
  // Example Remote Method
  myRemote(next: Function): void {
    this.model.find(next);
  }
}

module.exports = Account;
```

Finially, I've also attempted to use the [Loopback 3 Typescript definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/loopback/index.d.ts) but hit more problems as the PersistedModel methods here are all declared as static so fail type checks and return `Promise<T> | void`. The later means you’re forced to type cast the result back to just `Promise<T>` so it seems like the type def authors have never actually used  them. Is this a bug or am I missing something?  Can't find any working examples to prove otherwise.

This is the server side API pain. Client side REST API for Fireloop is also undocumented (lots of example for Real-time API) but none for the REST api it's also supposed to include (just mentioned once in one issue). Would be nice to find it can all be type checked by Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `ModelConstructor` validation methods were missing arguments like `{ message: 'my error message' }` and methods like `exists()` returned `Promise<any>` instead of `Promise<boolean>`.

The type definitions in [Loopback 3 Type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/loopback/index.d.ts) were more complete but were unusable unless fixed as described above.

In the end I used ..

```
# Used modified type defs from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/loopback/index.d.ts

import { Validatable } from '../types/validatable';
 # Fixed static methods and return types.
import { PersistedModel } from '../types/loopback';

constructor(public MyModel: Validatable | PersistedModel) {
  let Model = MyModel as Validatable;
  Model.validatesLengthOf('code', {
    min: 6, 
    max: 80, 
    message: { min: 'too short',  max: 'too long' } });
  Model.validatesFormatOf('email', 
    { with: this.reEmail, 
      message: 'invalid email address', 
      allowNull: false });
  Model.validatesInclusionOf('role', { 
    in: RoleNames, 
    message: 'is not valid' 
  });
}
```

And in later methods ..

```
let Model = this.MyModel as PersistedModel;

// knows that isFound is boolean
Model.exists(code).then(isFound => { ... });
```